# Display last WooCommerce Admin Order Note on customers My Account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I've connected PirateShip to WooCommerce. It pulls over the Order details and I create a tracking number and mailing label. It then sends the tracking number back to Woo as a 'Private Note' attached to the order.

**Example:** "Order shipped via USPS with tracking number 000." The number is clickable to the USPS web site.

I'm looking to improve *[Display last WooCommerce admin order note in customers order history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813313/display-last-woocommerce-admin-order-note-in-customers-order-history/55815353#55815353)* provided answer code

I would like the code to only pull out the number itself and have it clickable. Ideally, I'd like it placed above or below the Order Details header in My account view order like:

[image: See image here]

Any Help?