# Get only admin manual order notes (not "system") in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, orders

I want only to take manual order notes. I read about them and saw they are "internal" & "customer".

Based on [Display last WooCommerce admin order note in customers order history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813313/display-last-woocommerce-admin-order-note-in-customers-order-history/55815353?noredirect=1#comment118293490_55815353) answer code, here is my attempt:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );

// Get all order notes
$latest_notes = array();
    $latest_notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
        'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
        'limit'    => 'all',
        'orderby'  => 'date_created_gmt',
        //'added_by_user' => 'true',
) );


//if ( !empty($payment_title) ) {
echo '<div class="wc-order-preview-order-note-container">';
echo '<div class="wc-order-preview-custom-note">';
echo '<h2 class="order-note">Order Notes:</h2><br>';
foreach ($latest_notes as $latest_note) {
    echo $latest_note->content."<br>";
    echo "<small>".$latest_note->date_created->date('j F Y - g:i:s')."</small><br>";
}       
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
//}
```

This code gets all order notes.
Is there a way to filter only manual added?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the parameters from [wc_get_order_notes](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_order_notes/) is `type`

- `internal` is used for admin and system notes
- `customer` is used for customer notes
- leave empty for all

However, adding this param solves only part of your problem. So I believe you can use `added_by` and if it is not equal to **system**, continue

---

**Note:** in this example I used a static `$order_id`, replace with `$order->get_id()`
if desired

So you get:

```php
$order_id = 2279;

// Get all order notes
$order_notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
    'order_id' => $order_id,
    'orderby'  => 'date_created_gmt',
    'type'     => 'internal'
));

foreach ( $order_notes as $order_note ) {
    // Added by
    $added_by = $order_note->added_by;

    // Content
    $content = $order_note->content;
    
    // Compare
    if ( $added_by != 'system' ) {  
        // Date created - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
        $date_created = $order_note->date_created->date( 'j F Y - g:i:s' );

        echo '<p>' . $added_by . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $content . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $date_created . '</p>';
    }
}
```

---

To disable bulk actions comments too:

Replace

```php
foreach ( $order_notes as $order_note ) {
    // Added by
    $added_by = $order_note->added_by;

    // Content
    $content = $order_note->content;
    
    // Compare
    if ( $added_by != 'system' ) {
```

With (PHP 8)

```
foreach ( $order_notes as $order_note ) {
    // Added by
    $added_by = $order_note->added_by;

    // Content
    $content = $order_note->content;
    
    // Compare and string NOT contains
    if ( $added_by != 'system' && ! str_contains( $content, 'Order status changed' ) ) {
```

OR with (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)

```php
foreach ( $order_notes as $order_note ) {
    // Added by
    $added_by = $order_note->added_by;
    
    // Content
    $content = $order_note->content;
    
    // Compare and string NOT contains
    if ( $added_by != 'system' && strlen( strstr( $content, 'Order status changed' ) ) == 0 ) {
```