# Display last WooCommerce note to customer in My Account Order Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[This is my current recent order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOZCr.png)

I wish to add another column "Tracking Number" and it will show woocommerce "note to customer" inside.

result is like : [Display last WooCommerce admin order note in customers order history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813313/display-last-woocommerce-admin-order-note-in-customers-order-history)

The difference is without clicking view order and my customer can get to known their tracking number.

But I totally no idea how this work because not familiar with php..

hope to make this done and learn something.
Thanks!

the result will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to create a new column in My order page first

```
function order_note_in_column( $columns ) {

    $new_columns = array();

    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {

        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;

// Your Column Name : Change Tracking Number with the Column Heading you Want

        if ( 'order-status' === $key ) {
            $new_columns['track-number'] = __( 'Tracking Number', 'textdomain' );
        }
    }

    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'order_note_in_column' );
```

Once you create a new column now the second step is to display Data in the column.keep type as internal to show private note, In this way customer notes will not be displayed at frontend

```
function order_note_value_in_column( $order ) {
  
//Get Notes by order ID & Here keep type as internal to show private note. In this way customer notes will not be displayed at frontend  
 $note =    wc_get_order_notes([
   'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
   'type' => 'internal',
]);

// Displaying the latest Note. If no tracking number entered then order status will be displayed in column
print_r($note[0]->content);
  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_track-number', 'order_note_value_in_column' );
```

code goes in functions.php tested & works